# List of keyword arguments in plot recipe definition

Tags: julia

I have originally opened an issue in RecipesBase.jl, but I think this is just me not understanding the machinery of plot recipes. Why the code below fails when I try to pass in a list of keywords with the `...` syntax?

```
using RecipesBase

@userplot FooPlot

@recipe function f(fp::FooPlot; a=1, b=2, kwargs...)
    # SKIP
end
```

The error I am getting:

> BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{Any,1} at index [2]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure you can splat kwargs in a recipe.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisRackauckas, I will see if I can solve the problem differently. I should also open an issue on Makie.jl so that it hopefully gets fixed.